# All nodes getting selected with deep-equal in xquery

Tags: xquery, basex

I want to find all movies which don't have styles of anthology and art.
To achieve this I am using the following query

```
for $movie in db:open("movies","movies.xml")/movies/movie
where not(deep-equal(($movie/styles/style),("anthology","art")))
return $movie
```

However, all nodes are getting selected instead of filtering them.
What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query doesn't make much sense and deep-equal isn't useful here at all. The following will return all movies with a style not equal to anthology or art:

```
db:open("movies", "movies.xml")/movies/movie[not(styles/style = ("anthology", "art"))]
```